# Whats the easiest way to install Windows 7 via USB side by side with Ubuntu (Other Questions Below)?

Tags: grub2, partitioning, usb, windows-7, ntfs

I am trying to install Windows 7 side by side with Ubuntu. The computer is already running Ubuntu and I have partitioned the hard drive formatted it for NTFS and have a USB copy of the .iso of Windows 7. The usb is also formatted for NTFS and contains the .iso of Windows. People are telling me that I need to boot my computer from the USB via Grub.But I have no idea how to use Grub. So I need to know what commands to enter into Grub once I have it to boot the computer from the USB? How to install Windows 7 once I have booted off the USB into the blank partition? My computer is also fairly old so a lot of the recent keyboard commands don't work.

There has to be an easier way to do this. What is that?
What commands to enter into Grub to boot my computer off a USB?
How to install Windows 7 via USB to a separate partition of my hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need grub to enter windows 7 installation ,assuming your computer support USB boot. Open BIOS and change the boot order so that the USB comes first before your hard disk.

Opening of BIOS is done generally pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd> at startup.Look at screen corners while startup.For more info how to change boot order. consult your manual/help of motherboard (in case its a PC) OR user guide (for notebooks)). Once done, save and exit. The windows 7 installation will start.

Once windows 7 installation is done, it will overwrite the MBR, so grub (and ubuntu) won't be accessible. You need to boot again with live cd/ usb of ubuntu and use a tool called `boot-repair` to restore ubuntu with option to boot in Win 7. Using this tool is fairly simple, look at [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Preparing USB to make it bootable is missing (or booting from grub). Which is very important and without that there is no use of your answer.

Comment: @totti What? His answer is 100% useful. Granted, he could go into more detail re: Boot Repair and how to obtain/use it. Grub isn't needed to create or boot from the win7 USB installer. The BIOS should see the USB installer so long as it's created properly. Creating an installation USB of Win7 is beyond the scope of this website, so he is probably right in not providing a method to do so.

Answer (score 0):

First theres a tool in Ubuntu called start up disk, this one will install the boot aswell, next you have 2 options that depends on each motherboard:

1. Boot Menu, generaly F12, it will ask where you want to boot from and you only have to click USB and your good to go
2. go into bios and search for boot order, there you should put have something like 1-Hard Drive, 2-CD-Rom 3-USB, put 1-USB 2 Hard Drive. if you leave it this way after installation remenber to remove the USB or he will boot into USB again.

a good thing you should check is if the legacy USB is on in case he doesnt pick up